# DB2 SQL to suppress the spaces in a string

Tags: sql, sas, db2

I am a SAS user and I am trying to use SQL-PASSTHRU facility to run the queries. I want to know if there is a way to run the below functions (like in SAS).
Thanks in advance
Dharma

```
 data have;
     x='1 9 3 4 5 6 8'; 
    Birth_dt= '16jul1978'd ;
run;

proc sql;
    create table want as 
    select compress(x,, 's') as new_x,
           YRDIF(Birth_dt,today(),'ACT/ACT') as age 
    from have;
quit;
```

The answer looks like this

```
new_x age
1934568 42.170663972
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I am using DB2 SQL database to connect from SAS pass through facility

Comment: `select replace(x, ' ', '') as new_x, ...`

Comment: dnoeth, I have some records with double spaces as well. Can "replace" function will replace them with no spaces for double/triple spaces?

Comment: Of course, it removes every space.